# how could we install opencv on anaconda?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I tried to install OpenCV on Anaconda

```
pip install cv2
pip install opencv
conda install opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/jjhelmus opencv
```

(refered here [Anaconda doesn't find module cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22589157/anaconda-doesnt-find-module-cv2))

but all failed. Does anybody know how to install this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

I realized that opencv3 is also available now, run the following command:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

**Edit on Aug 18, 2016**:
You may like to add the "menpo" channel permanently by:

```
conda config --add channels menpo
```

And then opencv can be installed by:

```
conda install opencv(or opencv3)
```

**Edit on Aug 14, 2017**:
"*clinicalgraphics*" channel provides relatively newer vtk version for very recent python3

```
conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk
```

Comment: These options do not support FFMPEG

Comment: Also, [OpenCV can be installed through conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)  

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Answer (score 6):

I guess

http://answers.opencv.org/question/17536/install-opencv-for-anaconda-ipython/

it would be an answer

```
If you compile OpenCV from source, and Anaconda is your default python interpretor 
(CMake rule PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH = C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages), 
then the install rule will copy cv2.pyd to C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages.
Otherwise, you could do it manually, and make sure OpenCV libs are in the PATH.
```

Still I don't know what is CMake rule(?) and "install rule".

Comment: I have redirected cmake python path to anaconda python, then rebuild and install the opencv. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly go to your anaconda folder. The path in my case was -
C:\Users.....\Anaconda3 . Then go to the Scripts folder.
Open this link- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv .
Download this file - opencv_python-3.2.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl from the link and copy paste it into your Scripts folder inside Anaconda3 folder. 
Now go to spyder and type this,
import cv2
If everything works out it wont show any error and congrats you just installed it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda Python OpenCV-----------------

1. Remove all previous/current (if any) python installation
2. Install Anaconda and add anaconda to PATH(Envirnoment variables:: Adavanced system setting->Environment variables->under system variables go to variable PATHand click edit to add new envirnomental variables)
   (During installation check box involve PATH)
3. Open anaconda prompt with admin access. Type and enter:-
   conda update --all
4. conda install -c conda-forge opencv (for opencv)
5. conda install spyder=4.0.0  (spyder updation)
6. conda update python (for python updation)