# How do I install OpenCV for Python 3.4?

Tags: python, opencv

I use Python 3.4 through Anaconda distribution.  They don't seem to have Python 3.4 bindings for OpenCV.  I tried to use Cmake from the source, but to no avail.
Could anybody please help me to install OpenCV for Python 3.4.x?

Comment: What happened when you tried compiling?

Comment: When I ran the CMake utility, I got an error saying something is missing in the CMakelists.txt file in the OpenCV/source folder?

Comment: Hi ,  I got to the point of compiling and generating a build for Python 3.x.  But I don't know how to proceed from here.  How do I get the cv2 module working in Python 3.x

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3

Comment: I am using Windows 7, 64-bit.  The solution provided are for Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 8):

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Does the trick. However you have to have anaconda installed.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tutorials and questions (on SO) about this.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda) seems to answer your question. **Edit**: Reproduced below:

```
1)  Download OpenCV from http://opencv.org/downloads.html and extract

2)From the extracted folder, copy the file from the extracted directory:   
opencv/build/python/2.7/(either x86 or x64, depending on your Anaconda 
version)/cv2.pyd to your Anaconda site-packages directory, e.g., 
C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages

3)To get ffmpeg within opencv to work, you'll have to add the directory 
that ffmpeg is located in to the path (e.g., opencv/sources/3rdparty
/ffmpeg). Then you'll have to find the dll in that folder (e.g., 
opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll) and copy or rename it to a filename that includes 
the opencv version you are installing, (e.g., opencv_ffmpeg249_64) for 
2.4.9.
```

{End Reproduction}

**EDIT2**: OpenCV doesn't support Python 3.x except for OpenCV version 3.0 (still experimental, in beta). Download the 3.0 version from the download site and try that.(Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953273/install-opencv-for-python-3-3)).

<s>[A SO question with a possible tip, if the previous doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400935/how-could-we-install-opencv-on-anaconda)</s>

And finally, I will point you to a [read the docs tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html) on how to install it.

Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand much from this website.  Can you please tell me step-by-step how to install from the source if compatible binaries aren't already available?

Comment: Yes, I did that but I got the following error in Python-3.4:ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: The cv2.pyd under Python 2.7 is not compatible with Python 3.4

Comment: I installed the OpenCV version 3.0 beta, it still gives t he same error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Hi, I built OpenCV for Python 3.4 using CMake and MingW.  It builds successfully, but I don't know what to do from here.  How do I get the OpenCV module in the lib/site-packages folder in Python?  import cv2 doesn't work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is where things are murky, since this was just released. My suggestion would be to try following the steps that I had pasted above. Start with step 2. Also, make *absolutely* sure that the bitness (x86 vs x64) is the same as your python version.

Comment: There is no folder from where I can extract cv2.pyd.  I can't imagine there is not straightforward steps to install OpenCV for Python-3.x

Comment: As I mentioned, Python 3.x wasn't supported until recently. I am downloading the newest release now, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: No .download failed after an hour. I'll try again later today. I read [this](http://opencv.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/icvs/ICVS2013%20-%20OpenCV%203.0.pdf) which implies the Python related things are in "modules" try looking for that. If you do find it, try adding the directory the Python scripts are in to your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This is Quite Simple way:

I recommend to use through anaconda.

Create the environment in anaconda(recommended one):
`conda create -n deeplearning`

Then, activate by: `activate deeplearning`

Now, Install opencv for python3.x of Anaconda3 as:

- `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`

  > This will simply install opencv3 and other related libraries as: spicy, numpy, scikit-learn and matplotlib in that environment.

Check whether Opencv installed or not as:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.1.0'
```