# Anaconda: cannot import cv2 even though opencv is installed (how to install opencv3 for python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, opencv3.0

I have Anaconda (version: conda 4.2.9, python3) installed and am trying to do `import cv2` when I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
```

With `conda search cv2` I get this:

```
  opencv                     2.4.2                np15py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np15py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np16py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np16py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np17py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np17py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np15py26_1  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np15py27_1  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np16py26_1  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np16py27_1  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np17py26_1  defaults        
                             2.4.2                np17py27_1  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np16py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np16py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np17py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np17py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np18py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.6                np18py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.9                np18py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.10               np19py26_0  defaults        
                             2.4.10               np19py27_0  defaults        
                             2.4.10              np110py27_1  defaults        
                             2.4.10               np19py26_1  defaults        
                             2.4.10               np19py27_1  defaults
```

What do I need to do to be able to import the cv2 module?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Show me the command line history before and after opening python.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

opencv is not compatible with python 3. I had to install opencv3 for python 3. The marked answer in [how could we install opencv on anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400935/how-could-we-install-opencv-on-anaconda) explains how to install opencv(3) for anaconda:

> Run the following command:
>
> `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv`
>
> I realized that opencv3 is also available now, run the following command:
>
> `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`
>
> **Edit on Aug 18, 2016:** You may like to add the "menpo" channel permanently by:
>
> `conda config --add channels menpo`
>
> And then opencv can be installed by:
>
> `conda install opencv (or opencv3)`
>
> **Edit on Aug 14, 2017:** "*clinicalgraphics*" channel provides relatively newer vtk version for very recent python3
>
> `conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk`
>
> **Edit on April 16, 2020 (based on @AMC's comment):** OpenCV can be installed through `conda-forge` (details see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv))
>
> `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: _Edit on Mar 10, 2020: Hong's answer is the currently suggested way of installing opencv3 by Anaconda (see here)

conda install -c menpo opencv=3_ That package is unmaintained since late 2017, possibly earlier. OpenCV is available from the main Anaconda channel and from conda-forge.

Answer (score 12):

Use this code at the Anaconda prompt:

```
conda update conda -c conda-canary
```

Then don't type this code:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

but, instead, use:

```
Pip install opencv-python
```

It worked with me after few days of trials

See Krishna Ojha's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T2ykss_4Af0) and read the comments below the video.

Comment: Is this using anaconda with Python 3 or 2? Do you run the `pip` command from the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: Excellent answer, this worked for me 19/07/2020, you type all this in Anaconda prompt not cmd

Comment: 4/9/2023: I cannot believe that 3 years later this still seems to be the fix: I spent a a day trying to install opencv with conda and finally gave up. Installing with pip from the conda prompt took less than a minute!

Answer (score 11):

You can try

```
conda install -c menpo opencv=3
```

Comment: @padd13ear That package is unmaintained since late 2017, possibly earlier. OpenCV is available from the main Anaconda channel and from conda-forge.

Answer (score 5):

I had created my Anaconda environment and installed everything I needed, but when trying to import cv2, I always got the message "no module named cv2". I reinstalled and followed Linda's tips, which didn't work.

Finally, I noticed that my Anaconda environment didn't have cv2 installed, even with all I did.
I copied the cv2 folder to "miniconda'X'/envs/yourEnv/lib/python'X.X'/site-packages/" which worked for me.

Comment: this was driving me mad

Answer (score 3):

The file may be not installed properly.

Run the following commands:

```
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Check-in your jupyter notebook:

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

This may solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If aforementioned solutions don't work for you & you have opencv installed in conda environment then try the following command:

```
conda install nb_conda
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Anaconda Graphical Interface.

1. Launch Anaconda
2. Click on Environment
3. Select Target Environment
4. Select "All" from the list of Options
5. Search for "OpenCv"
6. Install