# Conda install and update do not work also solving environment get errors

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am using anaconda as below:

```
(base) C:\Users\xxx>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\xxx\Documents\ANACONDA
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\xxx\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\xxx\.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.11
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.6.9.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : C:\Users\xxx\Documents\ANACONDA  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\xxx\Documents\ANACONDA\pkgs
                          C:\Users\xxx\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\xxx\Documents\ANACONDA\envs
                          C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.11 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.9 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Now I have 2 issues that stop my work.
1) I cannot use `conda install` for any package.
It will give me the error in `solving environment` list this:

```
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

then it will fail again and give message like this:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

Even after the checking for incompatible packages, it didn't give me the solution.

2) When I want to upgrade or downgrade conda by the command:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

or

```
conda install conda = 4.6.11
```

It will give me errors again in the `solving environment`, and I think this is related to the first issue.

Now I cannot use conda for anything, please advise and thank you!

Comment: If anyone coming from Google has this issue and also uses conda-forge, try `conda config --set channel_priority flexible`. The source of the issue for some users (including myself) was `conda config --set channel_priority strict`.

Comment: "This can take several minutes." I LOLed. This process can run for *hours* and still not return anything. What I don't understand is that it already happen from a fresh anaconda install, without changing anything.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and I couldn't find a solution, but I did find a workaround. If you create an env and activate that env and then do the install, it seems to work just fine. If you don't need a lot of libraries I would try that.

Commands are:

1. Create env

```py
conda create --name myenv
```

2. Activate the env

```py
conda activate myenv
```

Comment: Although this is a workaround, but it seems the most feasible way to solve this problem. After having another env, the conda install works again and this time I only choose conda install as much as possible and carefully.

Comment: For folks like me who start creating a virtual environment using python, the environment has to be created using conda and not anything else.

Comment: Same problem here and a lot of users posting the same question on their Github page. Creating a new env seems to work fine. Otherwise it takes forever to solve the environment.

Comment: Is there really no other way? Creating a new environment is too large for my smaller drive so I can only use the base environment

Comment: I ran into this problem in a completely new environment I had just created, so apparently there's more to the problem than just a corrupted environment.

Comment: conda install -c anaconda python=3.8  I created an new environment and activated it then install python 3.8

Comment: `conda info --envs` to view your environments, `conda activate` to select one

Answer (score 59):

I started running in to this problem when one package suggested following modifications before installation

```py
conda config --set channel_priority true
```

so I just reverted it and voila error's gone

```py
conda config --set channel_priority false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me on conda 4.9.2. There was no need to downgrade conda to 4.6

Comment: Now **channel_priority** has different values: 'strict', 'flexible', and 'disabled'. Try `conda config --describe channel_priority` to get a description of these new values. `true` and `false` are still accepted but only act as aliases for flexible and disabled, while strict is a completely a new value that, if it finds the package you're trying to install into a high-priority-channel, completely ignores other channels disregarding the version they're providing.

Comment: this worked for me as well with conda 4.10.3 on macos.

Comment: this works for me too. I remembered setting it to Strict due to some package recommendation. Then forgotten to set it back. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Works for conda 4.13

Answer (score 25):

I solved a similar problem by doing the following:

```
conda update --all --yes
```

Comment: Solved my problem to install `pyarrow`. Thanks.

Comment: Solved my issue too, with contextlib2

Comment: Hmm, but still it becomes a sort of infinite process and it downloads packages once again.

Comment: Didn't work for me. conda 4.12.0, trying to install snowflake-connector-python.

Comment: Solved my problem with pathos. Conda forge website told me to execute `conda config --set channel_priority strict` and after this the problems started. `conda update --all --yes` reinstalled and updates some packages from `conda-forge` and installation of `pathos` was then successful (and everything works).

Answer (score 5):

You may downgrade to an older version of conda 4.6.14 and then install your packages.

```
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
```

Comment: As a side comment, if you go this route (which I did), you'll likely need a fresh anaconda installation for this to work

Comment: It's not wise to stay on an older version indefinitely.

Answer (score 4):

If your conda version is greater than or equal to 4.8, you may see that error.

```
(base) [localhost ~]$ conda --version
conda 4.8.2
(base) [localhost ~]$ conda install -c anaconda requests-kerberos
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
```

Downgrade your conda if possible using the following commands

```
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
```

Then create your virtual environment:

```
conda create --name myenv_conda
```

Then activate your myenv_conda

```
conda activate myenv_conda
```

Now try to install packages using conda -c install anaconda

```
eg: conda install -c conda requests-kerberos

output:
(myenv_conda) [localhost ~]$ conda install -c anaconda requests-kerberos
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done
....
....
....
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61117831/7802476 helped me. Creating a new environment using the accepted answer didn't get my jupyter notebook to recognize the installed opencv. I could only `import cv2` when I was in the environment on my terminal.

The fix was to use pip instead of conda, `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: Yes `opencv` is one of the higher visibility packages not natively supported by `conda`

Answer (score 1):

I run into same problem while installing `geopandas`. The issue was gone after I upgraded to a newer version of Anaconda using:

```
conda update --prefix C:\apps\anaconda3 anaconda
```

Note: you'll have to modify the path `C:\apps\anaconda3` pointing to your own installation directory.

Strangely, I did download Anaconda from the official homepage just a few hours ago and thought I had the newest version...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem but I solved because of SKİD.

After you create new env, You can run one of the codes in this link.

https://anaconda.org/rdkit/rdkit

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30979570)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by a Conda maintainer in https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8051#issuecomment-1549451621
their official position is that they know the old solver is slow and that is why they put effort in allowing the libmamba solver to be used in Conda.

To install:

```
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
```

at which point you are free to use it once, e.g.:

```
conda install tensorflow --solver=libmamba
```

or set as default solver:

```
conda config --set solver libmamba
```

It usually solves in seconds.

For more installation info see: https://conda.github.io/conda-libmamba-solver/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I've generally had good results with conda and pip, but learned over time that environments really can get broken by unusual combinations of packages, and just starting a new env from scratch is often the only way forward. In my case it was `tensorflow-gpu` that wouldn't install from conda-forge, into an env I'd already been using for some weeks. The list of packages cited as being incompatible was in the dozens. I tried all the things listed on this page, but in the end I just hammered out a new env. Since I was deducing what packages I needed to install in the new env by running my program and installing one package at each error (ie instead of being methodical about listing my former env), along the way I reproduced this frozen solve thing several times. Each time it happened, I shuffled that conda package back to the initial `conda create` command and started again. Eventually my program ran in the new env, with `tensorflow-gpu` imported, and the root cause was revealed as conda installs which occur after pip installs. It wasn't anything to do with conda version or conda config.

A specific note for anyone using `opencv-python`, I ended up needing to install `qt` via conda, before attempting to install `opencv-python` via pip. That was a tricky one because it's a runtime error, and on stack overflow many of the solutions refer to various qt lib requirements which aren't part of python/conda and which I already had.

A further specific note. Some pip installs will roll back a version of a related package, thus breaking other conda-installed packages. In my case the example was a package called `peakutils` rolling back `numpy`, which then broke a `from numpy import ma` in `scale.py` module in the `matplotlib` package. My head is still spinning.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new environment if your are not superuser, after that activate environment to install packages

Comment: It does not help, even the original author mentioned that such a method is problematic and it would be better to put channel_priority as false

Answer (score -3):

Recommend to upgrade conda latest version.

```
conda install --quiet --yes conda=4.7.11 
python -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.2.2
```

Comment: Still failed in solving env when trying to install conda=4.7.11, after it said`found conflict`, it went to package checking and stopped there forever...

Comment: stuck with same problem. pl anyone help

Comment: You can use conda=4.6, it's ok so far.

Comment: Same problem. Do you recommend downgrading from conda=4.7 to conda=4.6?

Comment: Downgrading to conda 4.6 helped me get around this issue and let me install specific versions of packages as normal.