# Problematic error while installing mysql connector

Tags: python, anaconda, mysql-connector-python

Whenever I try to install python mysql connector with the following command (base):

```
PS C:\Users\DELL INDIA> conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata s
```

it shows me the above mentioned error and doesn't get installed!!!

Pls help

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57597032/6505847

Answer (score 2):

I created a new environment in the navigator. With this new environment (and Python 3.8) it gave a clearer error message that Python 3.8 is not supported. I then created a new environment for Python 3.7 and it was able to be installed fine.

Comment: Faced the same issue in 3.9, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I searched for solutions, and one suggested to create a new environment with a lower version of python. I tried that - it worked, but that means I will have to reinstall all my packages. After trying several options, this is what worked for me:

`pip3 install mysql-connector-python`

Note that I used this on my main conda environment. Whatever made that work; I do not know.