# how do I install mysql on anaconda with this: Solving environment

Tags: mysql-connector, anaconda3

I'm a newbie when it has to do with installing packages through the cmd and would appreciate your help

I'm trying to install mysql-connector to my anaconda environment with this command:

```
conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python
```

and I get the following error:

```
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

I tried to the solutions suggested in this post but nothing works:
[Conda install and update do not work also solving environment get errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518050/conda-install-and-update-do-not-work-also-solving-environment-get-errors)
(meaning I tried creating another environment, than installing and also tried to run this
`conda config --set channel_priority false` but to no vail).

My conda version is the lastest - `conda 4.10.1`

here is the info for my conda

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\admin\anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\admin\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\admin\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.1
    conda-build version : 3.21.4
         python version : 3.8.8.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\admin\anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\admin\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\admin\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue
The problem was my python version 3.8, which does not support mysql-connector
Once I downgraded to 3.7.10 it worked perfectly fine